# Passing function of multiple arguments that contains class to other function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass function of multiple arguments to other function. I know how to pass a function of single argument function to other function as it was described in C++ primer plus book.

However, I get an error when I'm trying to pass multiple arguments with class(poly_3d) to NR_method function.

```
#include <iostream>

#define log(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;


class constants {
public:
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;

};

double poly_3d(double x, constants cst);
double NR_method(double a, double(*poly_3d)(double));


int main() {
    constants cst;
    cst.A = 2;
    cst.B = -8;
    cst.C = 10;
    NR_method(3.2, poly_3d);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

double poly_3d(double x, constants cst) {
    double y = 3 * cst.A*x*x + 2 * cst.B*x + cst.C;
    return y;
}

double NR_method(double a, double (*poly_3d)(double)) {
    double c = (*poly_3d)(a);
    return c;
}
```

So the error I'm getting is from NR_method(3.2, poly_3d) in main function. I know that if poly_3d was single arg, this would work.

If this is a horrible way to write codes, then any directions towards learning C++ more effectively for newbies would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You are simply missing the second argument in the declaration: `double(*poly_3d)(double, constants)`.

Comment: The global `poly_3d` takes two arguments (a `double` and a `constants` instance). The the second formal parameter for `NR_method` is a pointer to function returning `double` and taking *one* argument (a `double`). Therefore, `NR_method(3.2, poly_3d)` is malformed and cannot compile. I'm almost curious what you're *really* trying to do rather than just asking about what is wrong with the way you're trying to do it. As it stands now, the usefulness of `NR_method` is highly questionable, especially once it is "fixed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following code. We're using a template to make things look nicer.

```
#include <iostream>

#define log(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;


class constants {
public:
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;

};

/// Note that we take a ref now, no need to copy cst.
double poly_3d(double x, constants & cst) 
{
    double y = 3 * cst.A*x*x + 2 * cst.B*x + cst.C;
    return y;
}

/// Note that we take a ref now, no need to copy cst.
template <class F>
double NR_method(double a, constants & cst, F func) 
{
    return func(a, cst);
}

int main() {
    constants cst;
    cst.A = 2;
    cst.B = -8;
    cst.C = 10;
    NR_method(3.2, cst, &poly_3d);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I haven't learned what template is but I will for sure to study it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the function poly_3d with 2 arguments but passing only one. I made a few changes on the code for you

```
#include <iostream>

#define log(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;


class constants {
public:
    double A;
    double B;
    double C;

};

double poly_3d(double x, constants cst);
double NR_method(double a, constants cst, double(*poly_3d)(double, constants));


int main() {
    constants cst;
    cst.A = 2;
    cst.B = -8;
    cst.C = 10;
    printf("%f", NR_method(3.2, cst, poly_3d));

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

double poly_3d(double x, constants cst) {
    double y = 3 * cst.A*x*x + 2 * cst.B*x + cst.C;
    return y;
}

double NR_method(double a, constants cst, double (*poly)(double, constants)) {
    return (*poly)(a, cst);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize I needed to add constants cst. I thought that because I added in the first function, I didn't need to add them again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by simplifying your code. (A [minimal example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) removes distractions, allowing you to better focus on the actual issue.) It looks like you started to do this, but it can be taken further. After removing some stuff that is not needed to reproduce the compile error:

```
class constants {};

double poly_3d(double x, constants cst);
double NR_method(double a, double(*poly_3d)(double));


int main() {
    NR_method(3.2, poly_3d);
}

double poly_3d(double x, constants /*cst*/) {
    return 3 * x;
}

double NR_method(double a, double (*poly_3d)(double)) {
    return (*poly_3d)(a);
}
```

Now let's look at the error message:

> error: invalid conversion from '`double (*)(double, constants)`' to '`double (*)(double)`'

This comes with an indication that the conversion is from `poly_3d` to the second argument of `NR_method`. If you look at those things, yes, that is the conversion you requested. The argument list for `poly_3d` is `(double, constant)`, while the declared argument list for the second argument is just `(double)`. There is a mismatch, which makes the conversion invalid. It's not all that different from the single-parameter case: the signatures must match. You can solve this by changing the argument's signature to math that of `poly_3d`.

Now, if you just make the signatures match, there is another problem in that `NR_method` does not have a `constants` value available. That is probably a logical error for you to work out. For a quick workaround to show the elimination of the compiler error, I'll add a local variable.

```
class constants {
};

double poly_3d(double x, constants cst);
double NR_method(double a, double(*poly_3d)(double, constants)); // <-- Desired signature


int main() {
    NR_method(3.2, poly_3d);
}

double poly_3d(double x, constants /*cst*/) {
    return 3.0 * x;
}

double NR_method(double a, double (*poly_3d)(double, constants)) {
    constants cst;  // <-- Allows this to compile, but probably not what you want.
    return (*poly_3d)(a, cst); // <-- Needed a second parameter here.
}
```

There are ways to make this work nicer (for example, a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) may be more convenient than a function pointer), but explaining those would fall outside the scope of this question, especially since some decisions would depend on the bigger picture.

Comment: Thank you for giving detailed explanation and feedback sir. I really appreciate it!!